# case regarding method overriding of a class by subclass

Tags: java

I have developed the below class as shown below

```
class Ab {
    int i = 10; 
    static void getF() {
        System.out.println("I am good");
    }
}
class Hamm extends Ab {
    int i = 10; 
    static void getF() {
        System.out.println("I am good and bad boy");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Hamm h = new Hamm();      
        // h.getF(); //Ham
        Ab a = new Hamm();  //reference of parent class
        //a.getF(); // Ab class

    }
}
```

Now my query is there any scenario exisits where I am getting the variable i of class Ab but the method getF() of class Hamm, Please advise.

Comment: you can't override `static` methods.

Comment: not overiding we are only hiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the method to be non-static. You use it as instance method anyway. Static methods can not be overriden.

Here is a working sample:

```
class Ab {
    int i = 10; 
    void getF() {
        System.out.println("I am good");
    }
}
class Main extends Ab {
    int i = 10; 
    @Override
    void getF() {
        System.out.println("I am good and bad boy");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Hamm h = new Hamm();      
        // h.getF(); //Ham
        Ab a = new Main();  //reference of parent class
        a.getF(); // Ab class

    }
}
```

And a link on [ideone](http://ideone.com/dgB40O).

Answer (score 0):

When creating an instance of `Hamm`, the instance will use the variable and method defined on the child class `Hamm` since they will override the parents methods/fields.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and class variables (attributes) cant be overrided like instance methods (non-static methods).

Answer (score 0):

Methods in java are polymorphic. If you know C++ think that all non static methods are "virtual". It means that actual implementation will be called, e.g. in your case the implementation done in class `Hmmm`.

Fields however are not polymorphic, so `a.i` returns `i` variable that belongs to `Ab` class because `a` is a variable of type `Ab`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you have made your method static which hides the sub class's method. So each time you call the method, the method from your parent class is executed. And BTW since you have initialized the variable 'i' to 10 in both places, how do you know from where the value is coming?